# Delphi: TFileStream child class with progress event on read/write

Tags: stream, delphi, delphi-xe

i want implement a progress event on `TFileStream` for read/write operation for assign on it a progress bar.

I have create a clild class (`TProgressFileStream`) of `TFileStream`:

```
unit ProgressFileStream;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

type
  TProgressFileStreamOnProgress = procedure(Sender: TObject; Processed: Int64; Size: Int64; ContentLength : Int64; TimeLast : cardinal; TimeStart : cardinal) of object;
  TProgressFileStream = class(TFileStream)
  private
    FOnProgress:    TProgressFileStreamOnProgress;
    FProcessed:     Int64;
    FContentLength: Int64;
    FTimeStart:     cardinal;
    FTimeLast:      cardinal;
    FTimeDiff:      cardinal;
    FSize:          Int64;

    procedure Init;
    procedure DoProgress(const AProcessed : Longint);
  protected
    procedure SetSize(NewSize: Longint); overload; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const AFileName: string; Mode: Word); overload;
    constructor Create(const AFileName: string; Mode: Word; Rights: Cardinal); overload;

    function  Read(var Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; overload; override;
    function  Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint; overload; override;
    function  Read(Buffer: TBytes; Offset, Count: Longint): Longint; overload; override;
    function  Write(const Buffer: TBytes; Offset, Count: Longint): Longint; overload; override;
    function  Seek(const Offset: Int64; Origin: TSeekOrigin): Int64; overload; override;

    property  OnProgress: TProgressFileStreamOnProgress read FOnProgress write FOnProgress;
    property  ContentLength: Int64 read FContentLength write FContentLength;
    property  TimeStart: cardinal read FTimeStart write FTimeStart;
    property  TimeDiff: cardinal read FTimeDiff write FTimeDiff;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.Windows;

{ TProgressFileStream }

constructor TProgressFileStream.Create(const AFileName: string; Mode: Word);
begin
   inherited Create(AFileName, Mode);
   Init;
end;

constructor TProgressFileStream.Create(const AFileName: string; Mode: Word; Rights: Cardinal);
begin
   inherited Create(AFileName, Mode, Rights);
   Init;
end;

function TProgressFileStream.Read(var Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;
begin
  Result := inherited Read(Buffer, Count);
  DoProgress(Result);
end;

function TProgressFileStream.Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;
begin
  Result := inherited Write(Buffer, Count);
  DoProgress(Result);
end;

function TProgressFileStream.Read(Buffer: TBytes; Offset, Count: Longint): Longint;
begin
  Result := inherited Read(Buffer, Offset, Count);
  DoProgress(Result);
end;

function TProgressFileStream.Write(const Buffer: TBytes; Offset, Count: Longint): Longint;
begin
  Result := inherited Write(Buffer, Offset, Count);
  DoProgress(Result);
end;

function TProgressFileStream.Seek(const Offset: Int64; Origin: TSeekOrigin): Int64;
begin
  Result := inherited Seek(Offset, Origin);
  if Origin <> soCurrent then
    FProcessed := Result;
end;

procedure TProgressFileStream.SetSize(NewSize: Longint);
begin
  inherited SetSize(NewSize);
  FSize := NewSize;
end;

procedure TProgressFileStream.Init;
begin
  FOnProgress    := nil;
  FProcessed     := 0;
  FContentLength := 0;
  FTimeStart     := GetTickCount;
  FTimeLast      := FTimeStart;
  FTimeDiff      := 250; // ms
  FSize          := Size;
end;

procedure TProgressFileStream.DoProgress(const AProcessed : Longint);
var
  aCurrTick : cardinal;
begin
  if not(Assigned(FOnProgress)) then Exit;

  Inc(FProcessed, AProcessed);

  if FSize = 0 then
    FSize := Size;

  if FContentLength = 0 then
    FContentLength := FSize;

  aCurrTick := GetTickCount;
  if (aCurrTick - FTimeDiff > FTimeLast) or (FProcessed = FSize) or (FTimeDiff = 0) then
  begin
    FTimeLast := aCurrTick;

    FOnProgress(Self, FProcessed, FSize, FContentLength, FTimeLast, FTimeStart);
  end;
end;

end.
```

basic usage

```
uses ProgressFileStream;

procedure TWinMain.ProgressFileStreamOnProgressUpload(Sender: TObject; Processed: Int64; Size: Int64; ContentLength : Int64;  TimeLast : cardinal; TimeStart : cardinal);
begin
   if Processed > 0 then
      ProgressBar.Position := Ceil((Processed/ContentLength)*100);
end;

procedure TWinMain.BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  ChunkSize = $F000;
var
  aBytes:     TBytes;
  aBytesRead : integer;
  aProgressFileStream : TProgressFileStream;
begin
  aProgressFileStream := TProgressFileStream.Create('MyFile.zip', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  SetLength(aBytes, ChunkSize);
  try
    aProgressFileStream.OnProgress := ProgressFileStreamOnProgressUpload;

    aProgressFileStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    repeat
      aBytesRead := aProgressFileStream.Read(aBytes, ChunkSize);
    until (aBytesRead = 0);

  finally
    aProgressFileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Feature:

1. The event is called on each `TimeDiff` (public property) milliseconds for don't waste the performance on read/wtrite
2. The class has `ContentLength` property for set know size of stream, when the final size of the stream is unknow (eg. progressive download)

Point the attention on:

1. Performance
2. Stability/portability

Any other suggestion is appreciated.